# Css Content property to hold other classes

Tags: css, fonts

I have created a font that I would like to use as an icon using a font generator and Illustrator.

In the demo file, it has a bunch of spans that were the paths in Illustrator.

It is producing the html that looks like:

```
<span class="test-icon test-dashboard-icon">
   <span class="path1"></span>
   <span class="path2"></span>
   <span class="path3"></span>
   <span class="path4"></span>
   <span class="path5"></span>
   <span class="path6"></span>
   <span class="path7"></span>
</span>
```

I was wondering if there is a way to use the css content property to make all of these into one class where I can do something like `<div class="test-icon dashboard" ></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but you want to use **path-n** as inner HTML, you can use css counters, like so:

```css
.dashboard {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  counter-reset: number;
}
span {
  counter-increment: number;
}
span::before {
  content: "path"counter(number);
}
```

```html
 <div class="test-icon dashboard">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
     </div>
```

Comment: I'm not wanting to type all of the spans every time I use the icon